# Error de Relacion 1 a muchos en laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentado obtener e nombre de los estados de la republica en una relacion uno a muchos:

el módelo de Estados la relacion:

```
 public function empleado(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Empleado');
}
```

el módelo de Eempleados la relacion:

```
 public function estados(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Estados');
}
```

quiero obtener el nombre de los estados e imprimirlo en la vista, la consulta es:

```
$state = DB::table('estados as es')
    ->select(' es.NOMBRE', 'em.Estado_Actual_ID')
    ->join('empleados as em', 'es.id', '=' ,'em.Estado_Actual_ID');
```

pero cuando quiero imprimirlo :

```
dd($state->NOMBRE);
```

me sale el siguente error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$NOMBRE
```

cual es el problema;

Comment: duda ¿por qué usas un JOIN así y también a la vez usas los métodos de Laravel hasmany y belongsto?

Comment: Originalmente tenia una consulta que consultaba todos los registros y lo imprimia en la vista por medio de $states->nombre pero salia otro error que decia: Trying to get property of non-object y como vi en otros ejemplos que se podia acceder así pues lo intente pero de igual manera no funciono

Comment: haber, si la consulta funciona, en caso de que lo haga. La linea `$state->nombre` **estaria mal**, al realizar una consulta con `DB` en laravel este retorna un array. Asi que la linea en realidad seria: `$state[0]->nombre`, en caso de que por lo menos exista un dato, en caso de que la consulta retorne 0 datos, laravel enviara un error: **Trying to get property of non-object**

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a trabajar el ejemplo a través del uso de **eagger loading** pues al estar usando las relaciones de Eloquent se genera el problema de N + 1 por lo tanto para evitar múltiples consultas y limitarlo a dos hacemos uso del método with que recibe como parámetro el nombre del método que tiene asociada alguna de las relaciones de Eloquent

En el Controller **EmpleadoController** (asumiendo que lo tienes creado); crea el siguiente método:

```
public function empleados()
{
   $empleados = Empleado::with('estado')->get();
   return view('vista_name')->with(['empleados' => $empleados]);
}
```

Dentro del código anterior puedes observar que hago uso de eagger loading para hacer solo 2 consultas; esto lo identificas con el método `with()`

Fuente de consulta: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Dentro de la vista podemos recorrer la data del modo siguiente

```
@foreach($empleados as $empleado)
    {{ $empleado->nombre }}
    {{ $empleado->estado->nombre }}
@endforeach
```

> Como puedes observar en el foreach de la vista con la variable
>   empleado accedes al método estados que tiene la lógica de `belongsTo()`
>   con eso ya deberías poder acceder a la propiedad nombre

Observaciones a tu código

1. Dentro del método `belongsTo()` el nombre debe ser en singular; es decir estado
2. en el método que tiene `hasMany()` debe ser en plural empleados

Te armé la respuesta con lo que provees en tu pregunta, solo falta adaptes a tu escenario y pruebes