# ¿Cómo evito mostrar los resultados duplicados?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo esto en mi controlador:

```
public function create(City $city)
{
    $cities = City::all();
    return view('frontend/users/create', compact('cities'));
}
```

en mi vista necesito cargar las provincias y ciudades, Aquí consulto las ciudades porque están relacionadas con las provincias, pero el problema se presenta cuando muestra las provincias... Se repiten por la cantidad de registros que existe en la tabla ciudad.

También intenté hacerlo con el siguiente código:

```
public function create(Province $province)
{
    $provinces = Province::all();
    return view('frontend/users/create', compact('provinces'));
}
```

Me muestra bien las provincias pero las ciudades no, me muestra un JSON con `{{ $province->city }}`, y al tratar de acceder con `{{ $province->city->city }}` me dá el siguiente error:

> Property [city] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: Sí, en City (return $this->belongsTo(Province::class);) en Province (return $this->hasMany(City::class);)

Comment: En la vista de provinces:  foreach ($provinces as $province)
           <option value="{{ $province->id }}">{{ $province->province }}</option>
           endforeach

Comment: En las ciudades: foreach ($provinces as $province)
           <option value="">{{ $province->city->city }}</option>
           endforeach

Comment: respondí una pregunta similar en este enlace, te recomiendo revisarla, las tablas son distintas pero la idea a resolver es la misma que la tuya @Joe https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170809/error-de-relacion-1-a-muchos-en-laravel-5-5/172750#172750

Comment: Gracias, lo intenté y me da el mismo error, aunque no hice lo que dices del hasMany en plural, es una convención? porque mi tro archivo está en singular

Comment: Lo intenté como lo planteas en el post pero me da el mismo error, lo unico que mi nombre que está en el método está en singular puesto que el archivo se llama así. Afecta? o es solo convención de nombre de archivos?